# Equivalent of php to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, post

I'm trying to transpose this php sentence to jsp:

```
if(!empty($_POST){
}
```

Please I have been trying and I didn't resolved.

Comment: I would prefer a Servlet, and to override `doPost` and then use `RequestDispatcher` to forward to an appropriate JSP.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your environment.

If you use Servlet then you can refer to [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29).

The exact same code as yours

```
// In doGet or doPost  method of Servlet class
Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();

if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
}
```

If you're not on Servlet then complete your answer

Answer (score -1):

Just do it like this:

```
boolean isSet = (request.getParameter("your_parameter_goes_here") == null);
```

Comment: This is back to front.